# Singkil to Balai, how to?

Tags: transportation, sea-travel, indonesia

I heard there was a public boat but also some speed boat going from [Singkil (Aceh province, Indonesia)](https://www.google.co.id/maps/place/Singkil,+Aceh+Singkil+Regency,+Aceh/@3.2569621,98.4749023,7z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x302555ef15409169:0x4039d80b220d230) to Balai ([Banyak islands, Indonesia](https://www.google.co.id/maps/place/Pulau-pulau+Banyak,+Asantola,+Pulau+Banyak+Bar.,+Kab.+Aceh+Singkil+24784/@2.1659944,97.25,8z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x302522d8a6ec4a47:0xd26f1870ece6f641)).

Is this correct? is there other options of transportation? if yes, can you provide more details (time, price, comfort, safety, way of booking)?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banyak_Islands

[image: map of Banyak islands (Indonesia)]

Comment: A quick search turned up [this page from Sumatro Eco Tourism](http://www.sumatraecotourism.com/pulaubanyak/transportation.html), which lists some transportation details for Singkil, Kuala Baru and Pulau Banyak. Over half of that page is dedicated to travel from Singkil to Pulau Banyak, including some common routes, departures and prices, followed by a small remark on travelling within PB. Is that more or less what you're looking for? Note: the flight options on that page may also be relevant for [one of your other questions](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/49142/21954).

Comment: And for those who want to stay in Tailana island, here is some info about the accommodation available http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49746/accommodation-on-tailana-island-is-there-any-now-in-2015/50683#50683

Answer (score 7):

#### Public boat

There is a **public boat** going every morning (in June 2015). The cost for the public boat is 30'000 IDR (payment after journey). This journey takes around 3h30min.

Mind that the public boat schedule is very "peculiar". It leaves between 9am and 11am they will tell you (locals, tourists, agencies, etc). Reality is, it can take for a while for the boat to leave, even when they will tell you "we are leaving", there could be another hour waiting (yes, Sumatra style!). So be patient, and lower your expectations time wise.

You should also know that the public boat gets extremely crowded. See pictures below.

---

#### Fast boat

You can charter a **fast boat.** I didn't do that myself, but I met someone who did & told me it was horrible.

Basically, this fast boat is a tiny boat with a huge engine. It's very uncomfortable & you're half deaf when you arrive because the engine is so loud. If there are waves, you might just have the scariest boat ride of your life.

I can't remember the price for a fast boat sorry. The journey takes around 2h.

---

#### Public boat pictures

The public boat is the one on the very right.

[image: Public boat from Singkil to Balai]

The public boat once packed with its merchandise & passengers.

[image: Crowd on public boat from Singkil to Balai]

Comment: Adrien, could you please re-read the last paragraph and fix it? As it is, it's ...well... confusing.

Comment: @CGCampbell Sure, what about now?