# Accommodation on Tailana island, is there any now in 2015?

Tags: accommodation, beaches, indonesia, islands, remote-locations

Tailana island is a tiny island, part of the [Banyak islands in Sumatra, Indonesia](https://www.google.co.id/maps/place/Pulau-pulau+Banyak,+Asantola,+Pulau+Banyak+Bar.,+Kab.+Aceh+Singkil+24784/@2.7367582,97.6125488,8z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x302522d8a6ec4a47:0xd26f1870ece6f641). See Banyak islands map further down.

I found information on accommodation on Tailana island (Sumatra, Indonesia) on a ["Tailana island website"](http://www.tailana.webs.com/) & also on [SumatraEcotourism.com](http://www.sumatraecotourism.com/pulaubanyak/accommodation.html).

This place is pretty **remote**, so up to date info is very scarce. So I'm unsure the info on the website listed above is still correct.

Does anybody has up-to-date info from **2015**?

[image: Tailana island location in the Banyak islands]

---

#### Resources

http://www.tailana.webs.com/

http://www.sumatraecotourism.com/pulaubanyak/index.html

http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g2301775-i24868-k6981887-Which_island_accom_best_in_BANYAKS_for_pregnant_cple_2_y_o-North_Sumatra_Sumatra.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stayed in Tailana in end of **June 2015**.

There is currently a very small resort with 5 or 6 bungalows, each welcoming at least 2 people. The place is run by 3 locals who are quite nice.

The price for the accommodation is 100'000 IDR. If you want food (3 meals per day) & drinks (soft) included, then add another 100'000 IDR per person. So for 2 people in a single bungalow, count a total of **300'000 IDR**.

The bungalows are quite nice, although very simple. There was no moskitos when I stayed there. Bring a lock if you want to lock your bungalow btw. There is no electricity in the bungalows, but there is electricity in the common area of the resort (cafe/dining-room/kitchen) if you want to power up your devices. There are no toilets nor showers in the bungalows, these are shared. There is no drinkable water in the island, but there is a well where water is used for everything except drinking.

Food & drinks: drinkable water & most of the food is imported from nearby islands. Fishes are fished by one of the guys running the place (you can join him btw). Coconuts are from the island.

You can contact Hermann if you want to book [facebook.com/herman.pbb.9](https://www.facebook.com/herman.pbb.9), he is one of the 3 guys running the place.